# How can change the target branch for multiple Merge requests in Gitlab

Tags: git, gitlab, repository, gitlab-ci, gitlab-api

We have multiple open merge requests all pointing to one specific master branch. We are switching the default branch from master to another branch(called, trunk) for some consistency. The problem is, some repositories already have open merge requests that point to the old master branch. so is it possible to edit all these existing merge requests and change their target branch to point to the new master branch(trunk).

Comment: _Must_ you update them? Can't you just merge them to the old branch and eventually merge the old branch to the new branch, then phase it out?

Comment: @knittl there are over 200 merge requests, most of which are still in progress. so it is unclear when they will be ready to be merged. which means the old branch will stay for as long as the old mr still exists. until then I cant merge the old into new. however, I am trying to squash the old default branch as soon as possible

Comment: Why can't you merge old into new until everything has been merged? You can merge it frequently without problems. Only newly added changes will then be added to your "new" branch. Finally, after all PRs have been merged, delete the "old" branch.

Answer (score 1):

Use Gitlab API.

First, find all MRs where source branch is `master` :

```
GET /merge_requests?target_branch=master
```

from this request, get `project_id` and `merge_request_iid`.

Then, update all MRs with target branch `trunk` :

```
PUT /projects/:project_id/merge_requests/:merge_request_iid?target_branch=trunk
```

As your number of MR is consequent (200+), don't forget to use [Pagination](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/#pagination) to address all MR you want to get/update.